# aws NLB leads to time-out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-nlb

i have NLB which has target group to which 3 instance in different AZ are registered.

as i went through documentation NLB doesn't have security group. **so i added 3 inbound rules to ec2 instance security group which allow private IP of NLB's network interface from all the three AZ to send tcp traffic to ec2 instance.**

Note:- health checks to all 3 ec2 instances are healthy.

when i tried the same thing by allowing traffic my private IP there wasn't time-out issue.

Comment: If the instances are healthy, then where does time out occur?

Comment: Even i am surprised that instances are healthy, that means my rule of adding NLB interface private IP is working still not able to access my website from nlb  DNS hostname. my nlb dns http://network-lb-revision-cc9166c5264bbf59.elb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: The health checks are set for HTTP, not TCP?

Comment: no they are set for TCP protocol, i followed this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-find-load-balancer-IP/

Comment: Are you confident that NLB uses its internal IPs to communicate with your app? It [depends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#client-ip-preservation) on how you set it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marcin so apparently when you register target it get registeredbyinstance id for which client IP of all incoming traffic is preserved and provided to your applications.
so i just went to attributes of target group and disabled client ip preservation. When client IP preservation is disabled, the private IP address of the Network Load Balancer becomes the client IP for all incoming traffic now it works

would you mind to add this as answer so that it may help others in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Since NLB does not have security groups (SGs), the target instances need to allow either private IP addresses of NLB nodes or IP addresses of clients. This depends whether [client IP preservation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#client-ip-preservation) is enabled or not.

By [default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#client-ip-preservation):

> When you specify targets by **instance ID**, the client IP of all incoming traffic is **preserved** and provided to your applications.

Subsequently, SGs of the instances should allow all client IP addresses. Alternatively, you can **disable client IP preservation**, in which case, the SGs can use private IP addresses of NLB nodes.